# Makiing sql request on columns containing dot

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have  a dataframe having column'name containing "."
I would like to filter columns to get column's name containing "." and then make a select on it.Any help will be appreciated.
here is the dataset

```
//dataset
    time.1,col.1,col.2,col.3
    2015-12-06 12:40:00,2,2,3
    2015-12-07 12:41:35,3,3,4

val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
    val df1 = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/dataTestCsvFile/dataTest2.txt")
    val columnContainingdots=df1.schema.fieldNames.filter(p=>p.contains('.'))
    df1.select(columnContainingdots)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having dot in column names will require you to enclose the names with "`" character. See the below code, this should serve your purpose.

```
val columnContainingDots = df1.schema.fieldNames.collect({
  // since the column names has "." character, we must enclose the column names with "`", otherwise dataframe select will cause exception
  case column if column.contains('.') => s"`${column}`"
})

df1.select(columnContainingDots.head, columnContainingDots.tail:_*)
```